# Creating a "pivot table" like construct in sql

Tags: sql, pivot, case

This is going to be a bit convoluted but I have a table named dbo.sizeclassreport. I apologize if this is a bit vague.

It has 78656 rows/records which is not all that immense. There are three salient fields; employment, area, and sizeclass. Sample data below

```
Area     Employment    sizeclass
000003       4              01
000001       6              02
000013      12              03
000003       2              01
000005      23              04
000001       7              02
000003      11              03
```

From here, the result would look this. There are 9 sizeclasses and 18 areas. Need to produce 9 breakdowns of each area. Each area would have a breakdown by size class.

```
Area        Sizeclass     Employment in Size Class    Number of Sites
Total           00                17(6+11)                    3
000003          01                6 (4+2)                     2 
000003          02              NULL or Empty             NULL or Empty
000003          03                    11                      1
......
000003          09              NULL or Empty             NULL or Empty
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Ok, I will research the group by. Will this change my sizeclassreport table or will it be a separate entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    [Areas].[Area], 
    [classSizes].[sizeclass],
    SUM([data].[Employment]) AS [Employment in Size Class],
    /*this would be better with your PK */
    CASE COUNT([data].[Employment])
        WHEN 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE COUNT([data].[Employment])
        END  AS [Number of Sites]

/*These rows create your base matix*/
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Area] 
    FROM [sizeclassreport]) AS [Areas] 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                [sizeclass] 
            FROM [sizeclassreport]) AS [classSizes] 

/* this is where you select your data*/
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sizeclassreport] [data]
     ON [Areas].[Area] = [data].[Area] 
        AND [classSizes].[sizeclass] = [data].[sizeclass]
GROUP BY
    [areas].[Area], 
    [classSizes].[sizeclass]
ORDER BY
    [areas].[Area], 
    [classSizes].[sizeclass]
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks a lot. I am breaking this down line by line in an effort to get more proficient.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want all `area`s and `sizeclass`s in the output.  If so, use `cross join` to generate the results, then `left join` and `group by` for the calculations:

```
select a.area, sc.sizeclass,
       sum(scr.employment) as employment,
       count(scr.area) as number_of_sizes
from (select distinct area from dbo.sizeclassreport scr) a cross join
     (select distinct sizeclass from dbo.sizeclassreport scr) sc left join
     dbo.sizeclassreport scr
     on a.area = scr.area and sc.sizeclass = scr.sizeclass
group by a.area, sc.sizeclass;
```

Note:  This returns `0` instead of `NULL` for the last column.  This makes more sense to me.  However, you could use `NULLIF()` if you really want a `NULL` value.

Comment: Running that query now. Is it supposed to take in excess of 10 minutes to run?

Comment: cross joins will be slow if you have lots of data.

Comment: While I wait, what is the reason behind the a.area and sc.sizeclass? Just so I can construct my own next time.

Comment: This executed successfully but gave incorrect values. Let me do some thinking.